# High Performance Netem

Tags: performance

I need to use Netem to delay the packets according to a particular pattern. But I would need a resolution of less than 1 ms for the incoming packets. Do you know about any similar package that can perform with better precision than Netem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Netem can do better then 1ms if you increase the Hz config of your kernel (per default it is usually at 1000 which explains the 1ms). To figure out how to increase, just search the Internet for "Change linux kernel timer".

Comment: Good start.  Did you already modify your Hz config? How?